# Data too long for column in mysql

Tags: mysql

so I was trying to store SHA1 text into a column named "password" which was initially varchar(20) which was definitely less.

then I changed the size of the password column to varchar(40) and it still gave me the same error.

I even tried text and long text which should be enough to store 40 characters but still getting the same error.

some suggestions were to go to the config file and change the mode to "not strict".
I wanted to know if there's any other way.
what am I doing wrong?

query:

`call RegisterUser("test2","EF548F8AC757FAE6146574F365F64957F16D8A17","test2","test2",@returncode);`

the above query is running fine with small strings.

[screenshot of query and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhLWs.png)

Comment: Don't use SHA1 for passwords, use a dedicated password-hashing function.

Comment: please show us te code and the tables as sha1 has 40 didgits so it should be big enough

Comment: ok thanks, I figured it out. I was dwelling on it for hours. but I finally figured it out.

Comment: note the error says the column is `pass`, not `passport`.  please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table yourusertable` and `show create procedure RegisterUser`

Comment: @ysth yes, That's what caught my attention. pass is a variable of the stored procedure that I am using. so the error is definitely related to the stored procedure and not the table column. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was dwelling on it for hours but I figured it out. the problem was not with the column size. When I updated the column size in the table, I forgot to update the input variable in the procedure that I was using.
which was as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `RegisterUser`(
IN user varchar(20),
IN pass varchar(20),
IN email varchar(100),
IN phone varchar(12),
OUT returncode INT
)
BEGIN
    set @count = 0;
    SELECT count(username) INTO @count FROM login where username=user;
    if (@count > 0) Then
        set returncode = -1;
    ELSE
        set returncode = 1;
        insert into login (username,password,email,phone) values(user,pass,email,phone);
    End IF;
    select @returncode;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

In the above procedure, the **pass** variable had size **varchar(20)**. Changing it to **varchar(40) or char(40)** solved the issue as **SHA1 output is 40 characters long string**.

> so if you modify the column size in the table, you'll also have to
> modify the data type of input parameters of procedures accordingly.

I am working with procedures for the first time and so was totally unaware that the procedure will have to be updated too.
**Thanks for your help guys!**

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot username is still varchar(20)

Make sure it is large enough

Comment: error is because of column "password". which was initially varchar(20) but now it is LONGTEXT already. check the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

change the type data of column password from varchar to  LONGTEXT which provides a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 characters.

Comment: check the screenshot. it's already LONGTEXT.

Comment: FYI, LONGTEXT supports up to 4GB in bytes, not characters.

Comment: @BillKarwin good point. that's the reason why I posted this issue. The problem was with the stored procedure and not with the table column. thanks for the assistance though.